# Save validation rules on database

Tags: validation, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm not sure what is my question but I will try to explain.

Considering that every type in a domain model will become a rule or validation (or whatever) Strategy, what is the problem of persisting these validators on Database?

For example:

There is the followning model

```
public Class Contract
{
    ...
    public ContractType Type {get;set;}

    public bool Validate(){
        return Type.Validate(this);
    }
}

public abstract class ContractType
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }

    public abstract bool Validate(Contract contract);
}

public Class PreSale : ContractType
{
    public override bool Validate(Contract contract)
    {
        //here goes specific validation for PreSale
    }
}

public Class HighRiskSale : ContractType
{
    public override bool Validate(Contract contract)
    {
        //here goes specific validation for HighRiskSale
    }
}

public Class AprovedSale : ContractType
{
    public override bool Validate(Contract contract)
    {
        //here goes specific validation for AprovedSale
    }
}
```

I will use a Table Per Hierarchy approach to manage the concrete validators

Is it a damnable approach?

What are the problems of doing it?

**UPDATED**

The main argument I've been told, is that I should have a plain structure and get the rules from DI container or Service Locator, but i'm not comfortable of having a service locator on my Domain Model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many of these rules are there and how do you expect them to grow over time ?

Comment: There aren't many rules an grow it will depend on business change.

Comment: Why do you want to store them in the database ? Redeploying code in production is easy these days. Not that you should do it every day if you can avoid it, but redeploying to change a rule every few months is totally acceptable.

Comment: Actually my aim is just let the framework handle these rules without put an hardcoded rules or using a servicelocator in my Domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main question here is who is maintaining the rules. If the users maintain the contract and the validation rules for each contract then you might not even have an ApprovedSales class but a instance of the contractType class with a name "Approved Sale"
If you do that it makes a lot of sense to store the validation rules in the database (althoug be carefull, if your validation rules get complex so does storing them in the database)

If the contract types are fixed, combined with the validation rules, then just write them as linq queries (or however you want to write your validations) and hard-code them.

If you do want to store validators you might even look into storing them as json objects. The reason traditional databases work poorly is that if i have 2 validation, say age > 18 and Firstname at least 4 letters and only a-z then i have to store very different things in the database. If i use a TPH approach i might have a propertyname (age, firstname), number (18, 4) and allowedCharacters (a-z) field. But now you already see that the number field is used very differently for both validations. So i get 2 number fields 1 of them which always be empty..... a database can handle this of course but json serialization might even get there faster (if you want to store it) and if it doesn't change just coding them out is probally good enough for your customer (even if 2 years from now he wants to make a change to a contract, then you spend 2 hours in changing your code instead of spending now 2 hours on getting your database structure setup)

Comment: Aldana, The discussion that I want to rise is closer to Batavia considerations:
Since the user can change de contract types, might be problematic keep the rules on database, in the other hand, once every type demands coding, I mean, demands the creation of a Strategy which its type is concerned to, the user should never maintain the ContractType table.

Do youse agree that every type or status field in the system are undoubtedly rules?

Comment: @Dummy what do you mean by "the user can change the contract types" ? Do you want the user to be able to add new contract types through a UI ? To edit the rules for a contract type ? Or just change the contract type of a contract ? How does that make it "problematic keep the rules on database" ?

Comment: It is problematic because the users can update or add rules that they shouldn't without the due development and break the existing rules.
It isn't a problem disable rules but add a new one is a task that demands development

Comment: @Dummy, i would keep in the database what a user can actually maintain. If they just say yes/no to a rule then that's probally what should be in the database.(a boolean) If they can fully configure full field validations then you should store much more. as a general rule of thumb, make it simple, make it work first. and then look at if you need more configurability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with using the TPH approach, so.. Why not?

It is simple and seems to fit with the semantic behind your model.

I would consider another approach only if you think that those classes are going to incorporate lots of specific attributes that won't be shared between them and you think it would endup taking a lot of space on disk, or if you had to define null constraints over those fields.